# Image fromarray method is not working properly

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

i created a numpy array of size 10 by 10 with

```
x = np.eye(10, dtype=np.uint8)

[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

then i created a images out of it using fromarray method in pillow lib

```
im = Image.fromarray(x, mode='1')
im.show()
```

[image]

but the image is completely wrong. Then i converted the image to numpy array

```
img_arr = np.array(im, dtype=np.uint8)
```

it looks like this

```
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

the array is completely wrong.There are no diagonal 1's.
Can some help me ?

complete code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

x = np.eye(10, dtype=np.uint8)
print(x)

im = Image.fromarray(x, mode='1')
im.show()
im.save("D:\Desktop/fig.jpeg")
print(im.mode)

img_arr = np.array(im, dtype=np.uint8)

print(img_arr)
```

Comment: @Colim : but the mode is '1'.  I want it to be black and white image. Its not a gray scale image.

Comment: @Colim: but then it wont be black and white image

Comment: I made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use "1". Use "L"

```
im = Image.fromarray(x, mode='L')
```

if you really want to use mode "1", you have to encode in bytes. Every bit on each byte is a pixel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array(bytes([128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]))
im = Image.frombytes(data=x, mode='1',size=(8,8))
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
x=np.array([0b00010000,
            0b00101000,
            0b00010000,
            0b11111110,
            0b00010000,
            0b00101000,
            0b01000100,
            0b01000100],dtype=np.uint8)
im = Image.frombytes(data=x, mode='1',size=(8,8))
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks one more thing can you tell me how to convert a pil image obj to numpy bytes array

Comment: A byte is a numpy uint8, as shown on the second example.

Comment: to convert ìmg_arr to uint: `[ int("".join(map(str,row)),2) for row in img_arr]`